# Creating a very large random file

Tags: command-line

I wanted to create a 300GB file with random data so I used this command in terminal

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=random.txt bs=300g count=1
```

But what I receive is

```
dd: /dev/urandom: Invalid argument
0+0 records in
0+0 records out
0 bytes transferred in 0.000042 secs (0 bytes/sec)
```

I originally thought that is due to not writing `bs=300G` but capitalizing gives me `dd: bs: illegal numeric value`.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Does it work if you try smaller block size?  For example `dd if=/dev/urandom of=random.txt bs=1g count=300`?  I tried `bs=1g count=2` and it works for me to make a 2GB file - I don't have disk space for a 300GB.  btw it seems to take almost 1 minute per GB.

Comment: the bs data is the block size.  It must fit in memory/swap space.

Answer (score 3):

You can't read 300 gigabytes at once (in one block). Try

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=random.bin bs=2g count=150
```

instead.